# What am I not doing right in this django file upload form?

Tags: python, django, validation

This is my form:

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    titl    = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    ffile   = forms.FileField()
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file_path):
    print "handle_uploaded_file"
    dest = open(file_path.name,"wb")
    for chunk in file_path.chunks():
        dest.write(chunk)
    dest.close()

def handle_upload(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES["ffile"])
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks")
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    c.update({"form":form})
    return render_to_response("upload.html",c)
```

And this is the content of upload.html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/handle_upload/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload it"/>
</form>
```

Whenever I try to submit the form, I get a "This field is required" for the `ffile` field. What am I doing wrong? Just to mention, I am uploading a file each time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Documentation link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

Answer (score 43):

Just for future reference. I had the same error, though I included `request.FILES` in form initialization. The problem was in the template: I forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `<form>` tag.

Comment: God, how many different things I tried before reading this one :)
You'd think I would learn...

Comment: Specifying the encoding type on the template also worked on a class-based view, where one doesn't explicitly initialize the form to be able to pass `request.FILES` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks a load for this!

Comment: wow same here, just been bashing my head against this for an hr

Answer (score 0):

If you have included `request.FILES` and added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, but are **still** seeing this error, it could be you are not declaring the `<input>` correctly.

For example, if explicitly declare the input html in your template like:

```
<input type="file" value="Upload CSV File" />
```

You may not be passing the expected input id or name attributes of the input form element.

Be sure that your template is using the form element tag, i.e. `{{ form.file }}`,
which django will then render as: `<input id="id_file" name="file" type="file" required="">` on the page.